# Reuse assets across different rendering pipelines

Tags: unity, assets, asset-workflow

What is the best way to handle same project with two rendering pipelines that share 99% of the Assets?

We have one really big project for which we've decided to try and use both the URP and HDRP pipelines in Unity. Because of the way our application is setup (it acts more or less like a container) the only differences between the two pipelines from the Assets folder point of view are just 2-3 materials and another 2-3 shaders.

Our scripts are not important most of the code is in dlls and the output it to the correct location automatically.

The best thing that we came up was creating a directory junction between two folders inside of our assets and now the structure looks like this.

```
HDRP
└───Assets
    └───Custom
    |    |
    |    └─ Materials
    |          Material1.mat
    |          Material1.mat.meta
    |           ...
    └───Shared
         |
         └─ Materials
               Material1.mat
               Material1.mat.meta
               ...
URP
└───Assets
    └───Custom
    |    |
    |    └─ Materials
    |          Material1.mat
    |          Material1.mat.meta
    |           ...
    └───Shared
         |
         └─ Materials
               Material1.mat
               Material1.mat.meta
               ...
```

The junction was made for the `Shared` folders, where literally 99% percent or our assets are. The problem with this approach is that we're struggling to override the Shared assets with the custom ones (see my other [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/181533/override-assets-at-import-time)). I'd like to know if our approach is wrong and if so why? and what would be better.

Comment: did you try with git branch? try to make the base project without Render Pipelines then make branch for HDRP and URP